# How do I prevent scrolling in an HTML5 web page?

Tags: javascript, ios, html

How do I stop swiping and scrolling in an HTML5 web page? I have not using any script for that but still scrolling works. I am using jQuery, if it matters. This is the HTML code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>BRD</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.gif" /> 
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png"/>
        <link type="text/css" href="newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
            function showHideDiv() { 
                document.getElementById("one").style.visibility = "visible"; 
                document.getElementById("two").style.visibility = "visible"; 

                document.getElementById("three").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
                document.getElementById("four").style.visibility = "hidden"; 

                document.getElementById("radioone").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("radiotwo").style.visibility = "hidden";
            } 
        </script>    

        <script language"javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".text_paragraph").fadeIn();
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean page swiping? The following JavaScript should do it:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I want to stop page swaping and scrolling and where to write this code which you have given

Comment: but what if i want to stop only horizontal touch scroll then how to do that

Comment: There's a solution here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208905/horizontal-scroll-ipad. I don't have an iOS device so I can't test it. Make sure you remove the above JavaScript also.

Comment: i have posted a new question can you help me in that just start my work